# Input type="button" position absolute 2px difference in Firefox

Tags: firefox, input, position, absolute

I can't figure out, how to solve this problem.

Here some code - http://jsfiddle.net/Tmc8c/

```
<div id="top-auth">
<form method="get">
    <input id="login" name="login" type="text">
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password">
    <input id="login-button" name="login-button" type="button" value="Login">
</form>
```

Problem is that Login button displays 2px lower in Firefox. I try research but can't find anything to solve this.